# Using select and for loop to replace values in already existing columns

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

According to Sparks documentation this design is no longer recommended.

```
    for col in ['fl_ab_delivery_rbc', 'dr_ab_delivery_rbc', 'ab_delivery_rbc', 'wslr_delivery_rbc']:
        df = (
            df
            .withColumn(f"proposed_{col}", F.col(f"final_{col}"))
        )
```

Due to this reasoning.

[image]

I am trying to come up with an elegant solution that heads this warning. I've used a solution like this to create brand new columns never created before. However, since this column already exists and is set somewhere further up it basically just adds another column and I get a compilation error for having duplicate columns.

```
    col = ['fl_ab_delivery_rbc', 'dr_ab_delivery_rbc', 'ab_delivery_rbc', 'wslr_delivery_rbc']
    df = (
        df
        .select(
            '*',
            *[F.col(f"final_{c}").alias(f"proposed_{c}") for c in col]
        )
    )
```

Any ideas on how replace the already existing columns values with the values from the "final_{c}" columns without creating a duplicate?

Initially, my guess is changing the `.select("*")` portion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I think I've found the answer!

This is what is working for me

```
col = {'fl_ab_deliver_rbc', 'dr_ab_delivery_rbc', 'ab_delivery_rbc', 'wslr_delivery_rbc'}

df = (
    df
    .select(
        *(F.col(c) for c in df.columns if c not in col),
        *(F.col(f"final_{c}").alias(f"proposed_{c}") for c in col)
    )
)
```